# What does Java Web Start Run?

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks, java-web-start

What UI Framework does Java Web Start use? And where can I begin development for it? I'm running Netbeans but I'm fairly confused as to how Java Web Start works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWS can launch any rich client UI framework.  That means a J2SE based (J)Frame, or (J)Applet, or if you provide the necessary classes and natives on the server and specify them in the JNLP file, an SWT based UI.

Perhaps it would help to play about with some self contained JWS examples.  You can find a number of them in my [JNLP API demo. page](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html), which provides a zip archive of the complete source (JNLP, .java & an an ant based build file) of each demo.

Netbeans should be able to deal with Ant based projects with ease.